# Using Servlet to fill-in popup called from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, popup

my problem is possibly architectural. I have a page with number of items and when I click on the link I want to have a popup displayed with more information about the item selected. This information is pulled from the database.

In my opinion the architecture should be as such ...

1. JSP initializes a call to servlet and opens pop-up simultaneously
2. Servlet uses information from JSP to select item from database and passes information to pop-up page, this page is HTML
3. Pop-up displays information about the item

*There are several problems I'm seeing:*

1. What's the procedure for the browser to open the pop-up and use result from servlet? I don't want the page to load without having the results prepared by the servlet, this may be resolved by the session variables passed in from Servlet to JSP?
2. How should I pass parameters of which item was clicked on JSP to Servlet? JSP item portion  is being dynamically generated.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on my confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Use javaScript

Servlet response is basically an Http doc/snippet. 
So you could return a call to a javascript function that will be executed on the client side. 
The function can be passed in that Servlet response or it can be pre-included in the .js file.